# How to prevent script sharing from it's users?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making a small payment system, basically it's just a point system, you pay say 1 USD and you get 100 points which is used later on in a game project to get bonuses. It's a script for game servers, something like a user panel.

Now, the script system is ready, but I'm afraid to give it away, since than someone will share it and it will spread all over the gaming area. What would be the solution keeping it working only if I give them a permission?

I thought about re-making whole code and make it work on my website but I don't think that people will want to put their SQL data to website that located NOT on their host. Please help me out, at least with some clues, maybe its possible to make some widgets? or maybe some license system?

I'm really lost.

Comment: If you don't want to share something, don't publish it, that's the only way.

Comment: Well the thing is that I'm making this system only because many game projects want it. So i want to give it away only to competition winners once in a month

Comment: Can the system not be embedded into the game itself?  What are you talking about?  Sorry, saying "something like a user panel" tells me nothing at all!!!

Comment: Every game server ( mmorpg ) has a user panel where players register and modify their accounts. My panel has a point system also , sort of a shop. Of course panel is directly connected to game server sql database. Now you understand ? @LeeKowalkowski

Comment: Sorry, no.  I don't see any question about javascript, php or jquery!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement the logic on the server side as an api REST call and include in the script only an ajax call to the api. You can limit the use of the api through an api key that you'll provide only to qualified sites.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to implement some sort or serverside authentication/api so that only varified users can use the script. Much like how software checks a licence.

On script load your javascript could make a ajax call to a server passing through the users IP, auth key, username etc etc.

This can then be varified on the server, maybe returning a dynamically generated url containing a javascript file which contains your business logic
(so that urls are dynamically generated for that users session only)

That way people cant hot link the script, and the script you give out is solely the ajax call
(With the business logic script injected on auth)